# Building adjacency list in java

Tags: java, graph, depth-first-search

I'm trying to run DFS on an input in the form of 
1 2
3 1
2 3
5 6
4 6

that is 1 is connected to 2, 3 is connected to 1 and so on

just numbers listed representing to and from nodes. I want to build an adjacency list to link the corresponding vertices--is there a way to do this with just built in arrays in java??

Right now this is the code i have
`//initialize vertices

```
for (int i = 0, to = 1; i < n*2 && to < n*2; i+=2, to+=2) { 
    Vertex v = new Vertex (numbers[i]);
    v.next = new Vertex(numbers[to]);
   vertices[i] = v;
   System.out.println(vertices[i].value  + " " +vertices[i].next.value);}
```

but i don't think that this will work to link all the vertices then run DFS

Comment: Is this to say that 1 is connected to 2, 3 is connected to 1, 2 is connected to 3, etc? Is the graph directed?

Comment: Can you please describe the problem? You can use dynamic array, but the idea of adjacency list is - list.

Comment: the graph is not directed, and I'm trying to initialize vertices so that I can run a dfs main loop on them

Comment: Small point - Doesn't using i as the index in vertices[i]=v skip nodes as i is incremented by 2?   Does http://sites.harvard.edu/~libs111/files/ps10/Graph.java help?  The library uses the concept of edges (the to/from pair) and the vertices are initialized by adding edges.  See the methods initFromFile and addEdge.  These are similar to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the input type ? is it `int[]` ? What is the logic behind `6 4 6` ? If graph is not directed `64` and `46` are the same.  What is `numbers[i]`  ?  How is `Vertex` defined ?  Please **do not** answer all these question. Better  post [mcve] and clarify your question so we don't have to guess and assume.